# problem in mapping special characters in java

Tags: java

I am trying to map numbers and special characters using java but only alphabets are being mapped.Numbers from 0 to 9 and special symbols are not mapped.The output for this code is all the alphabets with their  alloted numbers but none of the number has been mapped.

```
import java.util.*; 

class maptable  { 
    public static void main(String args[]) { 
        Map<Character, Integer> hm = new HashMap<Character, Integer>(); 
        hm.put('A', new Integer(1));
        hm.put('B', new Integer(2));
        hm.put('C', new Integer(3));
        hm.put('D', new Integer(4));
        hm.put('E', new Integer(5));
        hm.put('F', new Integer(6));
        hm.put('G', new Integer(7));
        hm.put('H', new Integer(8));
        hm.put('I', new Integer(9));
        hm.put('J', new Integer(10));
        hm.put('K', new Integer(11));
        hm.put('L', new Integer(12));
        hm.put('M', new Integer(13));
        hm.put('N', new Integer(14));
        hm.put('O', new Integer(15));
        hm.put('P', new Integer(16));
        hm.put('Q', new Integer(17));
        hm.put('R', new Integer(18));
        hm.put('S', new Integer(19));
        hm.put('T', new Integer(20));
        hm.put('U', new Integer(21));
        hm.put('V', new Integer(22));
        hm.put('W', new Integer(23));
        hm.put('X', new Integer(24));
        hm.put('Y', new Integer(25));
        hm.put('Z', new Integer(26));
        hm.put('0', new Integer(27));
        hm.put('1', new Integer(28));
        hm.put('2', new Integer(29));
        hm.put('3', new Integer(30));
        hm.put('4', new Integer(31));
        hm.put('5', new Integer(32));
        hm.put('6', new Integer(33));
        hm.put('7', new Integer(34));
        hm.put('8', new Integer(35));
        hm.put('9', new Integer(36));   

        Set<Map.Entry<Character, Integer>> st = hm.entrySet();

        for (Map.Entry<Character, Integer> me : st) { 
            System.out.print(me.getKey() + ":"); 
            System.out.println(me.getValue()); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: What is the question? Works fine for me.

Comment: The code you provied works - take a look http://tpcg.io/X36TtJ.

Comment: You should avoid creating new `Integer` objects using the constructor. Instead use `Integer.valueOf(int)`. In your case, you could also let the compiler auto-box the integer values, for example `hm.put('Z', 26)`.

Comment: Just for the record: open up an ascii table, and see how the characters are "numbered". Then look up the details of the java base type `char` ... to then conclude: you don't need that mapping table at all. You can use simple maths to get from an int to a specific char, and backwards. Finally: read about Java naming conventions. Class names go UpperCase, and abbreviating names is discouraged. "hm" means nothing. Call it intCodeByChar for example.

Answer (score 1):

The code works.

A HashMap is not ordered, however somewhat ordered by the values' hashCode.

This might mean you see the letters first or last; as their hash codes might use their int value.

One problem might be the special characters. Java text is done in Unicode (`String`, `char` ), but `char` holds only UTF-16. Hence a chinese Unicode symbol might be translated into two `char`s (called *surrogate pair*). For such usage it is better to use Unicode *code points*, in java of type `int`.

Another problem when for instance using Hindi or Arab numerals is that the compiler must use the same encoding as the editor (check the IDE), otherwise the bytes in the .java file are interpreted differently. Nowadays international projects generally use Unicode UTF-8.

In general one would expect at least see 26+10 lines in the code above, even if some of them are garbage. Or otherwise an exception with stack trace on an illegal byte sequence (typically with UTF-8) or unsupported encoding.

One problem often is the command line, that might use the limited single-byte encoding of the system.

---

Finally a small improvement:

```
    hm.put('Z', Integer.valueOf(26));
    hm.put('0', Integer.valueOf(27));
```

Java caches some Integer objects, normally from -128 upto 127.

Also java can automatically *box* primitive-type (=char/int/double/boolean/...) values with `valueOf`.

```
    hm.put('Z', 26);
    hm.put('0', 27);
```

In fact you did this already unknowingly (?) for char 'Z': `Character.valueOf('Z')`.

Answer (score 0):

#### Be simple!!!

```
public static int convert(char ch) {
    if (Character.isAlphabetic(ch))
        return Character.toLowerCase(ch) - 'a' + 1;
    if (Character.isDigit(ch))
        return ch - '0' + 27;
    return -1;
}
```